# I can't install Firebase pods via terminal (on Mac) because I say my folder is a directory

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, macos, cocoapods

I can't install the pods which are in my Podfile...
here is my pod file:

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'I deleted the target name' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Order Corner V4
# add pods for desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

And now, I want to install all these Pods, (the first of the I already have installed separately) with the terminal command 'pod install'... But I gives me the Error

> Path_to_my_Folder/Name_of_my_Folder:  is a directory

I don't know what to do because it works great the last time, I have already installed Firebase/Core with this way.

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate` before `pod install`

Comment: The Problem is when i use a pod-Statement in this directory I get this output: -bash: /Users/me/Desktop/ProblemOrdener: is a directory

Comment: I really don't know what's to do because I cant do any command

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the podfile. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods) which state

> The Firebase iOS library Firebase/Core is no longer needed. This SDK
> included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.

Your podfile should look like this

```
project ‘your project name.xcodeproj’
platform :ios, '14.0'

target ‘your project name’ do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

If you've already installed a pod, it would be best to remove existing pod and start fresh. In terminal, ensure cocoapods is current

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

if that command throws an error, try this

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Then navigate to your projects directory and do this to remove existing pods

```
pod deintegrate
```

then do this

```
pod install
```

After that be sure to open your project with the .xcworkspace file

If you need to create a fresh podfile, navigate to your project directory and do this

```
pod init
```

which will create a Podfile.